# How can I check string contains only a-z

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a few strings like these:

```
$str = 'this is a test 1';
$str = 'this is a test س';
$str = 'this is a test!';
$str = 'this is a test';
```

And I want this output:

```
false // there is this number: `1`
false // there is a Arabic character: س
false // there is a exclamation mark
true // that's pure English
```

As you see, I need to determine a string is pure-English or not. How can I do that?

Comment: what is **pure** English ??

Comment: @Dagon it is just containing `a-z` characters plus whitespace.

Comment: Do you mean to validate that the string has only base ASCII _letters_ and whitespace?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes exactly.

Comment: then that should be the subject line

Comment: @Dagon That question you flagged isn't the same with mine...! It isn't sensitive to whitespace and it language is asp and mine is php.

Comment: regular expressions are language agnostic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming *"pure English*" = English letters + space:

```
^[a-zA-Z ]*$
```

- `[a-zA-Z ]` - defines a character set containing lower and upper case letters + space
- `*` - repeat any number of times
- `^$` - make sure the string is matched from the start (`^`) til the end (`$`)

Comment: Just for my information, How can I add all symbols *(`!`, `.`, `@`, `#`, `^`, `%` and etc ..)* to it?

Comment: @Shafizadeh, you can add them between the brackets. However, be careful - some characters have special meanings. For example don't put the `^` at the beginning of the brackets, because then it would have the meaning of negation.